# Creating a formula in a Rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logic, formula

I would like to create a small formula in my view/home page. Basically it should say if current user signed in (got that part right) AND USER CREATED A REGISTRY = TRUE then this
or that.

Here is the code below:

```
 <% if user_signed_in? and?????? %>

 <%= link_to "Show My Registry", current_user.registry %>

 <% else %>

 <%= link_to "Create a new registry", new_registry_path %>

 <% end %>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "created a registry" is too vague for anybody to help you. Is a registry another model? Is there a relationship between the two?

Comment: Yes, registry is a model. Each user can create one registry. Belongs to and has one. Everything works. Just want to sort out the home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Registry` is a model that belongs to a `User`, you could use `<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.registry.exists? %>`

Comment: Why does it say:undefined method `exists?' for #<Registry:0x41ce4d0>

Comment: Could you post what you have changed in your source code and the error message you're getting now?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you all ready have the relationship between Users and Registries established. If so your if so you could create a method in your users controller that looks something like.

```
def user_registry
  User.current.registry
end
```

Then if your view your if statement should look something like

```
<% if user_signed_in? and user_registry? %>

<%= link_to "Show My Registry", current_user.registry %>

<% else %>

<%= link_to "Create a new registry", new_registry_path %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to nest the two decisions. What happens if the user is not signed in? Do you still want the user be able to create a registry without signing in? Other option would be to consider using a before_filter to ensure user is always signed in before she gets to this decision point in your app.